# Prevent text from updating in AvalonEdit but propagate Event

Tags: avalonedit

I know I can subscribe the `textEditor.TextArea.TextEntering` and set the `e.Handled=true` to prevent the user from typing a certain character, but the problem with that approach is that it stops the event from bubbling. For instance, I want to prevent the user to type a Carriage Return / Line Feed but allow the event to propagate and eventually validate my window if a validate button is present.
Thanks in advance.